# Multi line h1 header based on pixel width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a multiline header based on width. Here is an example:

```
<div class = "col-lg-12">
 <h1> 
  Long title: I am learning html and web design. Also, I love data science. Stephen curry is killing everyone
  <small> by Me</small>
 </h1>
</div>
```

The code above produces a header that spans beyond the browser's right border. I would like to turn it into multiple lines by specifying width. I tried wrapping `<h1>` into another div, `<div style = "width:50px"><h1>...</h1></div>`, but it didn't work. I include the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55wv853x/). Help appreciated.

Comment: Is the 'closing' `h1` tag a typo in the question or is it in your code too? Should be `<h1> 
  Long title: I am learning html and web design. Also, I love data science. Stephen curry is killing everyone
  <small> by Me</small>
 </h1>`. The `col-lg-12` will be the full width so you'll need to put a width on the `h1` to stop it being full-width too as it's a block level element by default.

Comment: @martincarlin87 typo. Edited.

Comment: Have a look at http://fittextjs.com/. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: it's a little unclear: in your question, you have a normal sentence, while in your fiddle, you have a very long word... so is your problem with breaking words or something totally different?

Comment: @mijopabe as far as I know fittext.js changes the size of text hwereas I want to preserve the size of the text and break a long header into multiple lines based on width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `word-break: break-all;` to your h1 style. Default value is "normal", and it works without breaking words in the middle, of course.

http://jsfiddle.net/55wv853x/3/

About WORD BREAK:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle. Is this what you have in mind?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/55wv853x/6/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 wrap">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1> eruheri uhgui rehguireh giurehg ure hgheriu</h1>
        <p> by Me</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```